# how to change the display value in a cell (gridtable) in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, setvalue

without touching the value of the list or using field updater, how can you to change the value of a cell in the datagrid.

i have found `myDataGrid.getColumn(0).getCell().setValue(context, parent, value);` but I dont know what context and parent is

Comment: you need to update the specific row of the underlying Provider. This is either a `ListDataProvider` or a `AsyncDataProvider` and then call `table.redrawRow()`

Answer (score 0):

you can change the bean's property value which is used with datagrid, then do refresh row. 
    that will update cell also.

```
table.redrawRow(absRowIndex);
```

Comment: but how can you change the value? can i use .setValue(context,parent, value)?